# Getting an EOF Error in my code and i dont know what that means

Tags: python

I am getting this error in my code and I have never had it before and I have no idea what is causing it to happen. Does anyone know how I can fix my code and can someone explain what this error means?

> ERROR: Traceback:
> in <module
> in simple_encoder
> EOFError: EOF when reading a line

```
def simple_encoder(s):
    users_string = input("please enter a scentence to encode")
    users_stringlower = users_string.lower()
    encodedstr = users_string
    for x in range(0, len(users_string)):
        indexnumber = 0
        count = users_stringlower.count[indexnumber]
        LetterToEncode = users_string[indexnumber]
        if count > 1:
            encodedstr = encodedstr.replace(LetterToEncode, ']')
        elif count == 1:
            encodedstr = encodedstr.replace(LetterToEncode, '[')
        indexnumber = indexnumber + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually, `EOFError` refers to an [End Of File error](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/handling-eoferror-exception-in-python/#:%7E:text=EOFError%20is%20raised%20when%20one,input%20in%20the%20input%20box.). That means that your program called `input()` but failed to have any available input to read.

We cannot run the code you posted because we're missing some variables, like `NumOfIterations`.

Comment: Vtasca I realised I had typed it up wrong I have fixed it now.